# How to know WindowsFormsHost Rendered Size which is placed in a TabItem of TabControl?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am developing a Wpf application which is having a TabControl with 3 tab items and each tab item consists of one WindowsFromsHost.On Startup of the application the WindowsFromsHost.ActualHeight and WindowsFromsHost.ActualWidths are coming 0. How to get the rendered size ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could able to get the ActualWidth and Actual Height using below code

```
_winFormHost.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate(Object state)
                    {
                        _height = (int)_winFormHost.ActualHeight;
                        _width = (int)_winFormHost.ActualWidth;
                        return null;
                    }), null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Loaded event of your TabItem. On the startup is too early to get the size of your controls.

ActualWidth and ActualHeight are fine for rendered size.

Example:

Xaml:

```
<TabItem x:Name="aaa" Loaded="aaa_Loaded">
```

Code behind:

```
private void aaa_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  //get rendered size
}
```

Comment: can you please explain the below answer ?